# Accessing this array with various parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello i'm trying to access the data_ parameter of this array but i couldn't get it

```
pa {then_: Array(0)}
data_: 3
state_: "fulfilled"
then_: undefined
__proto__: Object
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Copying and pasting text from the console is not particularly useful. Even `console.log(JSON.stringify(pa))` would be better. What is this _object_ and where does it come from and most importantly, what have you tried?

Comment: What did you try yet?

Comment: i use var paginas = doc.getPageCount(); and console.log(paginas);

Answer (score -1):

Arrays are indexed and can only be accessed using `bracket notation`.  The example code here doesn't seem to be proper?  But I am assuming we are talking about an object here instead of an array.  To access the `data_` property of this object you can use either `dot notation` or `bracket notation`.

In my example I will name the example object `exampleObject`.

```js
exampleObject._data;
exampleObject['_data'];
```

hope this helps!

Comment: I'm trying to get the total pages from a pdf
 var paginas = doc.getPageCount();  
and console.log(paginas);  
  returns the array  it didn't work out the way you mentioned it shows me undefined

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what ```doc.pageCount()``` does.  Can you post a screenshot of what paginas is?